# Request a reference in group theory

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, representation-theory

Although the book "A Course in the Theory of Groups" by Derek J.S. Robinson is an excellent up-to-date introduction to the theory of groups and covers various branches of group theory, it is hard for a beginner (not in mathematics, but in some topics of Algebra) to understand all the proofs of the theorems with many parts that are supposed trivial.

My question is specifically about the chapter 8 of this book. This chapter is about Representation of groups with subtopics: Representation and modules, Structure of the group algebra, Characters, Tensor Products and representations, and applications to finite groups.

**My question is:
Is there any references with the same topics which can help me in better understanding? Also about the exercises of the book "A Course in the Theory of Groups", where can I find the solution of these exercises or some hints about solving them?**

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Introduction to the Theory of Groups by Rotman is very good for general group theory. A good introduction to representation theory is Linear Representations of Finite Groups by Serre, which is pretty much the standard.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful guidance. Is there any book which can help me in solving the exercises of the book "A Course in the Theory of Groups"?

Comment: Well, I don't know but the problems in the book will all be solvable using the material contained in it! I don`t know if there is a cole`s notes type thing. There is always Stack Exchange

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentals of the theory of Groups by Kargapolov